# Open Layers 2 Creating and adding Feature to Vector Layer from Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, openlayers, geojson

as title suggest, create Feature and add it to already created vector layer. I am fetching GeoJSON from server and trying to somehow add to vector layer but I can't get it to work... So basically I am asking how to get Feature element from my GeoJSON, so I can add it to vector layer.
What I currently have..

This is my GeoJSON fetched from server :

```
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[20.5629940201429,48.9488601183337],[20.5630121528311,48.9489447276126],[20.563289335522,48.9489141101973],[20.563260061873,48.9488286413488],[20.5629940201429,48.9488601183337]]]]}
```

next I have addVector function in JavaScript where I'm trying to the magic.(variable GeoJS is GeoJSON fetched from server)

```
function addVector(geoJS){
    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector( new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon(geoJS) );
    vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Magic"); 
    map.addLayer(vector);
    vector.addFeatures([feature]);
}
```

and yep I know that second line where I creating feature is wrong, but i cant make it right so i guess id doesn't matter what I write there for now...
I tried it with `var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-70.702451, 42.374473);` and it worked position on the map was not where I want it to be but I know that i have to do something with projection... It just doesn't matter now.

and btw I have this

```
vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON",
{
    projection       : "EPSG:4326",
    onFeatureInsert  : postIns,
    strategies       : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol         :  new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                            url: "test.php",
                            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                        })
});
```

And this works, position is where I want it, its perfect except it only works when I make request on my domain, and server I try to reach is on another(I know I can set headers and it would work) but I don't want to do it this way.

So basically I am asking how to get Feature from my GeoJSON. I am really new to OpenLayers so I'm sorry if I asking something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a simplified version of [the official example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/geojson.html):

```
var inputGeoJson = '...some-GeoJSON-here...';
var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
map.addLayer(vector_layer);
vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(inputGeoJson));
```

You can find more details in the [GeoJSON class documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON.read).

Comment: Thanks Kryger, But I cant say it works because drawn polygon is really tiny just dot on a map and when I start zooming in, it just disappear.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, not related to your original problem. Also, consider using gis.stackexchange.com for GIS-specific questions like GeoJSON, projections, maps, etc.